# Can I go back to the rest of the level once I beat Mom?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

Am I really leaving behind everything on the Depths 2 after I enter the boss room? I had left behind a blood donation machine and a full health pill and everything else!

Comment: I want to say "no" you can't - but there's probably some glitchy way to do so (ie, telepills or similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope you can't revisit the rest of the level, not without some sort of teleportation.  From the BoI Wikia article on [Mom](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Mom):

> You can't leave the room without teleporting, as the door is gone, so make sure to check every room and pick up every item you want before encountering Mom! (A door to the devil room may appear after a teleportation.)